# Django Rest Framework How to call variable from one method in another?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use only one View Class in Django with two methods **post()** and **get()**. Post is being used to get user session Token that I want to make available in **"get()"**, so that I can identify the current user and send user details using the same view via Serializer. I want to use that token to get the name by **user = Tokens.objects.get(key=token)** to get the username and then filter **User.objects.get(username=user)** to post user data in the front end. How could I make "token" available inside **def get()** so I can work with it? Thank you!

This is my View.py:

```js
class UserDetails(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args):
        serializer = UserAccountTokenSendSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            global token
            token = serializer.validated_data['token']
            self.get(token)
            # user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
            # global current_user
            # current_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
            # email = User.objects.get(email=user)
            # print(current_user, email)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get(self, request, *tokens):
        username = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        email = User.objects.get(username=username).email
        serializer = UserAccount(username, email, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

These are my 2 serializers to post and get data:

```js
class UserAccountTokenSendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccountTokenSend
        fields = (
            'token',
        )
        
class UserAccount(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'username',
        )
```

This is my model to send token from frontend to backend:

```js
class UserAccountTokenSend(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This is my urls.py:

```js
    path('get-user-tokens/', views.UserDetails.as_view()),
    path('get-user-details/', views.UserDetails.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, seems like you need to do the following:

```js
class UserDetails(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserAccountTokenSendSerializer(data=request.data)
        # GLOBAL MAKES IT AVAILABLE FOR ALL METHODS IN THAT CLASS
        global token
        if serializer.is_valid():
            token = serializer.validated_data['token']
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user =  Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        details = User.objects.get(username=user)
        print('#########################################', user)
        serializer = UserAccount(details, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You don't need to do anything, because from what I was managed to find is that if you post data from a serializer in Class, when you declare a variable as Global it becomes available for all of the methods in that same Class.

Answer (score 0):

I will asume that you are using authtoken model of drf and your token model has a one to one relation field with user.

```
class Token(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
```

So in your User serializer

```
class UserAccount(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(source='token.key', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'username',
            'token',
        )
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use that. In the front-end I get localStorage that shows the token, but not the user. That's why I am trying to make it available in get() so that I can use it to find other user information.